# On the regularity of $ \int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(a + t(x - a))\,\mathrm dt $

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $ U\subset \mathbb R^n $ be star shaped with respect to $ a\in U $, and let $ f\colon U\to \mathbb R $ be a $ \mathscr C^\infty $ function.

Is it the case that for each $ i = 1,\dots,n $ the function
$$
h_i(x) = \int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(a + t(x - a))\,\mathrm dt
$$
defined on $ U $ is a $ \mathscr C^\infty $ function?

Comment: yes, and the partial derivative only serves to distract you. Look at $F(x)=\int_0^1f(a+t(x-a))\,dt$. Now, you need some basic version of Leibniz’s rule for differentiating under the integral sign.

Comment: Quite surprisingly I never learned Leibniz's rule (the one for integrals, I mean). Are you claiming basically that since $ g(x,t) = f(a + t(x - a)) $ is differentiable in $ x $ (for $ t $ fixed) and continuous in $ t $ (for $ x $ fixed), then $ F(x) = \int_0^1 f(a + t(x - a))\,\mathrm dt $ is differentiable, and so on inductively?

Comment: yes essentially that (well what you said is not quite the assumptions of the theorem, but the assumptions (eg as listed on Wikipedia) are definitely satisfied since $f$ is $C^{\infty}$).

Comment: But what guarantees me that the function $ g(x,t) = f(a + t(x - a)) $ is continuous? I thought that maybe $ g $ is uniformly continuous in $ x $ if $ f $ is (at least) $ \mathscr C^1 $, but this seems not to be the case. (I found a cute description of the Leibniz rule on the second volume of Zorich's _Mathematical Analysis_, btw).

Comment: you said $f$ is $C^{\infty}$, so by composing it with the obviously $C^{\infty}$ function $(x,t)\mapsto a+t(x-a)$, shows that $g$ is $C^{\infty}$ on the open set $\Omega=\{(x,t)\,:a+t(x-a)\in U\}$ (and ok if you really want to go down the rabbit hole, the chain rule talks about differentiability of a composition in terms of differentiability of each function at the appropriate points, but now a simple induction argument lets you go all the way to $C^{\infty}$).

Comment: Oh you're right! (And probably I should sleep more...)